# Python. Error al realizar un loop con while

Tags: python

Me gustaría tomar todos los valores de una compra y dar el valor total de la compra aplicandole el IVA.

```
    def get_factura ():
        factura=[]
        while factura != 'salir':
            producto = input('Producto: ')
            precio = float(input('Precio sin IVA: '))
            print(f'El producto {producto} tiene un precio sin IVA de {precio}')
            factura.append(precio)
        return factura
    listado_compra=get_factura()
    print(listado_compra)


    def factura_IVA(factura):
        total = 0.0
        for precio in factura:
            total+= precio
        precios=round(total+0.21*total,2)
        return precios

    precio_total = factura_IVA(listado_compra)
    print(f'La factura total con IVA es de {precio_total} €')
```

El problema es que estoy realizando un loop con while y no se corta cuando le escribo salir.
¿Cuál es mi error?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el código que has adjuntado tienes varios errores.

1. `factura` es una lista, por lo cual se usa el operador `in` para comprobar si el valor existe.
2. La lista `factura` nunca va a contener el valor salir, ya que solo le estas añadiendo el precio.

La solución que te propongo seria usar un flag para comprobar si el valor introducido es igual a `salir` lo que hará salir del bucle y seguir con las siguientes instrucciones.

Código:

```
def get_factura ():
    factura=[]
    salir = True #Flag para indicar cuando salir
    
    while salir: 
        producto = input('Producto: ')
        if producto == 'salir':
            # Simplemente salimos del loop
            salir = False
        else:
            # Seguimos con el programa
            precio = float(input('Precio sin IVA: '))
            print(f'El producto {producto} tiene un precio sin IVA de {precio}')
            factura.append(precio)
            
    return factura
    
listado_compra=get_factura()
print(listado_compra)
```

Comment: funciona correctamente, muchas gracias Eugeni